# Evaluating Artin symbol

Tags: class-field-theory

Consider the field $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.  Let  $mp=\frac{(2+\sqrt{2})^{p}-1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$.

For the field extension, $K(-1+2\sqrt{2})/K$, and $p\equiv 5\bmod{6}$ how can one show

$ \frac{(2+\sqrt{2})^{p}-1}{1+\sqrt{2}}\equiv 1\pmod{-1+2\sqrt{2} }$ 
and hence, Artin symbol corresponding to $ K(-1+2\sqrt{2})/K$, is trivial,

where as over  $ K(-1-2\sqrt{2})/K$

$ \frac{(2+\sqrt{2})^{p}-1}{1+\sqrt{2}}\not\equiv 1\pmod{-1-2\sqrt{2} }$. I  workedout as to take, $-7=(-1+2\sqrt{2})(-1-2\sqrt{2})$ and evaluate $mp$ mod  at 7. Any Hint is also welcomed.

Comment: We have $\sqrt2\in K$, so $K(-1+2\sqrt2)=K$, and the extension is trivial, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I got  this doubt, while evaluating norms of Mersenne primes, to represent it in the form $x^2+7y^2$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  is this statement true: $Frob_{7} (2+\sqrt{2})\equiv 2+\sqrt{2} \pmod{-1+2\sqrt{2}}$ is identity, hence the Artin symbol is trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Galois group of the extension $K(-1+2\sqrt2)/K$ is trivial, so all the Frobenius automorphisms are equal to the identity for lack of alternatives.

In the specific example from comments we can also check it as follows. You already showed that $(-1+2\sqrt2)\mid 7$. Therefore
$$2+\sqrt2\equiv2-6\sqrt2=-1-3(-1+2\sqrt2)\equiv-1\pmod{(-1+2\sqrt2)}.$$
Hence
$$
(2+\sqrt2)^7\equiv(-1)^7\equiv(-1)\equiv2+\sqrt2\pmod{(-1+2\sqrt2)},
$$
that is compatible with the Frobenius being the identity.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this what you were asking. I still have problems putting all the pieces together. Also I'm not very familiar with class field theory.

Comment: @
Jyrki Lahtonen, thank you very much.